# Is there a way to programmatically know when a Python function is done processing?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, scheduled-tasks

Here's a brief background of what I've done so far:

- I have a table in a database with unprocessed data marked with a flag
- I have create a python script that utilizes the multiprocessing library to break this task onto the available cores of the device this script is running on
- Each process receives a subset of records to work on and once it has completed, it writes the results onto the same table

My end goal is to repeat this process in a routinely fashion i.e. as soon as the task above is done running, I wish to have the python script to run again to check for unprocessed data. I have looked into a library that performs scheduling (https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) and other similar ones. However, those libraries seem to be time driven. My question is: is there a way to use the function end as a trigger to start it up again? Is there a way to know by code if a function is done running to run it again?

Comment: What about just using queues and have the functions fetch from the queue when ready?

Comment: Can queues be used indefinitely?

Comment: Just call the function within the `while True:` loop? Maybe what you want is to know when all the processes finished their jobs, right?

Comment: I have tried using an infinite loop in my main function, however, it only calls the module function once. `while True: module.doSomething()`

Comment: Queues can be used indefinitely. Jobs can be submitted to a queue by a main process and secondary processes can take jobs from the queue. You could use that in conjunction with a process pool.